# My break code doesn't break my code

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, break

Read below. I got it fixed.

Yes I've asked this already and yes people suggested me to use .equals but it still doesn't work.

My problem is that my code doesn't breaks the for loop.

```
for(int l=0; l<1000; l++){
    if(settings.getString("note" + l, "").equals("")){
        if(settings.getString("notelong" + l, "").equals("")){
            editor.putString("note" + l, title.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("notelong" + l, note.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            break; // This should break the loop BUT IT DOESN'T...
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Yes it runs break. Else it wouldn't create the notes

EDIT 2: Sorry, this for loop was in another for loop and I forgot to break the first one... now it works! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Does `settings.getString("note" + l, "").equals("")` even ever return true? Use `Log.i()` to determine that.

Comment: @bellabax. If `break` doesn't work. That wouldn't work either.

Comment: Check your assumptions; I'm reasonably certain `break` works as advertised.

Comment: Add SOP after the `break;` statement. if it doesn't work - it should print to catlog.

Answer (score 2):

Either

```
settings.getString("note" + l, "")
```

or

```
settings.getString("notelong" + l, "")
```

(or both) do not return an empty string. If they don't, your *equals* comparisons return *false*. In which case, it never gets into *break* statement. For your *break* logic to work, both *if* statements need to be *true*.

Comment: @user2124499 So it goes inside if it is 1000, for the rest it doesn't result to be true. You can remove the loop and have the value of l to be 0 or 1 and see if it goes in.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `break;` line is actually being run. Do both the if statements equal true on the same iteration? That could be the problem.

Use the debugger in eclipse and walk through it.

Answer (score 1):

remove your first `if`, and check if your second `if` is equal true on any iteration.